# How can I resolve the scope of variables in a julia expression?

Tags: julia

Is there any way to run name resolution on an arbitrary expression without running it? e.g. I would like to take an expression such as

```
quote
    x = 1
    y = 2*x + 1
    z = x^2 - 1
    f(x) = 2*x + 1
end
```

and be told that the names defined in the scope of this block are `x, y, z, f` and the names `*, +, ^, -` are pulled in from outside the scope of this block. Bonus points if it can tell me that there's a sub-scope defined in the body of `f` which creates it's own name `x` and pulls in `+` from an enclosing scope.

This question appeared in the [Julia Zulip community](https://julialang.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/225542-helpdesk/topic/running.20name.20resolution.20within.20a.20macro/near/212615562)

Comment: You could deconstruct the whole syntax tree. If you find expressions which use names not assigned or defined in the current scope, they were pulled from the outer scope. Hope you get the idea :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [Takafumi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/727827/tkf) for [showing me how to solve this on Zulip](https://julialang.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/225542-helpdesk/topic/running.20name.20resolution.20within.20a.20macro)

We can get a list of locally defined names in the outermost scope of a julia expression like so:

```
ex = quote
    x = 1
    y = 2*x + 1
    z = x^2 - 1
    f(x) = 2*x + 1
end
```

```
using JuliaVariables, MLStyle

function get_locals(ex::Expr)
    vars = (solve_from_local ∘ simplify_ex)(ex).args[1].bounds
    map(x -> x.name, vars)
end

julia> get_locals(ex)
 4-element Array{Symbol,1}:
  :f
  :y
  :z
  :x
```

and we can get the symbols pulled in from *outside* the scope like this:

```
_get_outers(_) = Symbol[]
_get_outers(x::Var) = x.is_global ? [x.name] : Symbol[]
function _get_outers(ex::Expr)
    @match ex begin
        Expr(:(=), _, rhs) => _get_outers(rhs)
        Expr(:tuple, _..., Expr(:(=), _, rhs)) => _get_outers(rhs)
        Expr(_, args...) => mapreduce(_get_outers, vcat, args)
    end
end

get_outers(ex) = (unique! ∘ _get_outers ∘ solve_from_local ∘ simplify_ex)(ex)

julia> get_outers(ex)
 6-element Array{Symbol,1}:
  :+
  :*
  :-
  :^
```